# How to prepare KF/Al2O3 i.e. potassium fluoride on alumina (/on aluminum oxide)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, catalysis

It's surprisingly hard to find an answer to this. One book I found referenced a method wherein one would simply mix (with a mortar I assume?) equal (another source said 40:60) portions of Al2O3 and KF and that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Bull. Chem. Soc. Jpn.*, **1983**, *56*, 1885-1886 ([PDF](http://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/pdf/10.1246/bcsj.56.1885)), the authors (*Takashi Ando* and coworkers) give the following method:

> Alumina (30 g, neutral alumina, type 90 for column chromatography, activity I, 70-230 mesh, Merck Jpn.) was mixed with $\ce{KF}$ (20 g) in 200 mL of water and the water was removed at 50-60 °C in a rotary evaporator. The impregnated alumina was then dried in a vacuum drying oven at 75 °C for several hours.

In another publication, *J. Chem. Soc., Perkin Trans 2*, **1986**, 1133-1139, by the same main author, which focuses on the properties of the $\ce{KF}/\ce{Al2O3}$ system, a "dry preparation" by *grinding* $\ce{KF}$ and $\ce{Al2O3}$ *under a nitrogen atmosphere* is mentioned.